# WinForms - Reloading Dynamically Created UserControl

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

My application gets a list of files creates a panel for each file with a delete button an puts all of the panels in a flowPanel Layout. While 
it is creating the panels it shows a loading panel. See the link below. All that works great. My issue is once a file is deleted I need to reload the flowpanel from the updated directory where we just deleted a file.

Since I have to make my onclick static to keep the RunAsyncProcess() method happy. I cant get back to my UI to reload the control. I hope this make sense. I'm struggling to even find the right search terms for google on this.

Reference to the loading panel methods such as RunAsyncOperation(MyDelegate1); found here.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24044/AJAX-style-Asynchronous-Progress-Dialog-for-WinFor

Here is how my control is loaded.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SuspendLayout();
        Control ctrl = Parent.Parent.Controls.Find("MainControlPanel", false).First();
        MyControl myControl = new MyControl();
        myControl .Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Parent.Controls.Remove(this);//removes a menu control
        ctrl.Controls.Add(myControl);
        ResumeLayout();
    }
```

Here is the control

```
bool isLoaded {get; set;}
List<Panel> panels {get; set;}

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
         isLoaded = false;
         panels = new List<Panel>();
         RunAsyncOperation(MyDelegate1);
         RunAsyncOperation(MyDelegate2);
         while (!isLoaded) { //just wait }
            foreach (Panel panel in panels)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
            }
}

AsyncProcessDelegate MyDelagate = delegate ()
{
     //setting up the ui
     string[] list = ...
        foreach(in list)
        {
            Panel p1 = new Panel();
            Button btn = new Button()
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(MyEvent); // my event must be static
            p1.Controls.Add(btn)                
            panels.Add(p1);
        }

     isloaded = true;

}

AsyncProcessDelegate MyDelagate2 = delegate () 
{
            while (!isLoaded)
            {
                //showing the loading ui
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
};

public static void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            Modifies string[] list  and needs to reload
            is there a way to call onload again?
            How can I make it reload

     //this does not work
     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
     RunAsyncOperation(MyDelegate1);
     RunAsyncOperation(MyDelegate2);
     while (!isLoaded) { //just wait }
        foreach (Panel panel in panels)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panel);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added flag to show changed data

```
static bool reload { get; set; }
```

Added to onload

```
stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            reload = false;
            stopwatch.Start();
            PollUpdate();
```

Added poll method to check if we should reload

```
public void PollUpdate()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (reload)
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    reload = false;
                    SuspendLayout();
                    Control ctrl = Parent.Parent.Controls.Find("MainControlPanel", false).First();
                    AudioLibraryControl cr = new AudioLibraryControl();
                    cr.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    Parent.Controls.Remove(this);
                    ctrl.Controls.Add(cr);
                    ResumeLayout();
                }
                Application.DoEvents();

            }
        }
```